# Add xcode-select to PATH vs. Install Xcode Command Line Tools?

Tags: xcode, path, bash, command-line-tool

Now with Xcode 4.5, is it OK to just add the following line to my `~/.bash_profile` rather than installing the Xcode Command Line Tools?

```
export PATH="$PATH:`xcode-select -print-path`/usr/bin:`xcode-select -print-path`/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin"
```

Note: Xcode says the following about Command Line Tools:

> Before installing, note that from within Terminal you can use the
>   XCRUN tool to launch compilers and other tools embedded within the
>   Xcode application. Use the XCODE-SELECT tool to define which version
>   of Xcode is active.  Type "man xcrun" from within Terminal to find out
>   more.